# PropertyGrid-like multiselection in other elements(listView)

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, propertygrid, multi-select

i want to immitate the behavior of multiselection of items (eg. in a list view) and their appearence in a PropertyGrid. So, obly the same properties are shown and values set in the grid are set on all multiselected properties.

I have created a listview with some datatemplates and have in another listview some data(with databinding). Now i want wo have a multiselection on the listview with the data and have the properties shown in the another listview like in a propertygrid.(explanation: The ProprtyGrid is still not available in WPF and if has not the flexibility of showing data the way i need it)

So, how do i need to prepare my data to be shown in the list propertygrid-multiselection-style? Is that even possible???

Greets,

Jürgen

Comment: There's a propertygrid here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87715/Native-WPF-4-PropertyGrid ... http://wpfpropertygrid.codeplex.com/   or http://wpg.codeplex.com/ ... Also these might help... http://grokys.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iii.html ... http://www.mindscapehq.com/forums/thread/3105

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this question is still active, or what not. But I have found a solution that works for me - and I need somewhere to share it.

The first issue you are going to have solve is selecting the items, ie. multi-select. See my tip [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582670/Multiselect-ListBox-ListView-items-like-Windows-Ex) that explains how to do that.

Next, I guess its basically binding to listview's selectedItem property and how you want to update your propertyGrid based on changes to the selectedItem prop.

Hope this helps.